# How to add a navigation controller to a subview of a parent view

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a design where I have a main view controller, with three subviews contained within. How can I add a UINavigationController to one of the subviews to manage the view stack for that subview only?

Answer (score 1):

Since iOS 5 you can create custom container view controllers. I recommend creating a container that holds your 3 views (each of them being view controller objects). And since `UINavigationController` is a `UIViewController` subclass, you should be able to add it to your container.

Comment: Yeah, I was exploring that. Once I add a navigation controller as a child of my container view controller, whose frame should I be setting to place it correctly? The navigation controller's, or its root view controller's?

Comment: View controllers (and thus navigation controllers) don't have frames. Only views have. You probably have to set the navigationController's rootViewController's view's frame. But I'm not 100% sure right now how containers work. It's been a while since I last played with that.